# Find last filled row without opening file and with conditions

Tags: excel, vba

**What I wish to do :**

```
i.   Locate an excel document using path and doc name √
ii.  Obtain the last filled row’s number with a spreadsheet name without opening the file X 
iii. Obtain the last filled row's number BEFORE a certain row number, X
     ex: last filled row before row 40. There may be filled cells between 45-52, 
     but I would like the function to return say "32" and not "52" like it does for me
```

**What I have:**

The path to the file is a classic directory + file name, which are written in two separate cells in the spreadsheet that has the macro. It's irrelevant, just to show that File_Path = the path ...

```
File_Path = Chr(34) & Server & "\" & Range(Workbook_Loc).Value  'That's step one
```

In the file located at File_Path, I wish to go in the spreadsheet named MONTH YEAR (ex: File_Path("July 2015")) and find the last filled row's number. In the 3rd line, I try to fill a cell with the last row's value in B. I know there is a lot online for this, but I can't get it to work somehow...:

```
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(File_Path) ' This should open my workbook
lastRow = wb(Chr(34) & Month & " " & Year & Chr(34)).Cells(1000, col).End(xlUp).Row 
Range(CurrentValue_Loc).Formula = "=INDEX('" & Server & "\" & Workbook & Month & " " & Year & "'!B" & lastRow & ",1)"
```

The previous code stops at the second line ; it opens the workbook located at File_Path and gives me the following error:

```
Run-time error '438'
Object doesn't support this property method
```

What am I doing wrong?

Finally, for my iii. point (see top example), I tried to do this:

```
    lastRow = wb(Chr(34) & Month & " " & Year & Chr(34)).Cells(40, col).End(xlUp).Row
```

but it still gives me the last filled row, even if it is after row40

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to type the name of the workbook again, when attempting to find the last rows. Just use the workbook variable, which you have already set.

```
Sub lastRow()
    Dim lastRow As Long

    lastRow = wb.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    lastRow = wb.Sheets(1).Cells(40, 2).End(xlUp).Row
End Sub
```

Just use the variable you have already declared, and then the `Sheets()` [method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194464.aspx) to define the sheet you're finding the last row on. In the example above we are finding the last row on the first worksheet in the workbook.

Comment: This still opens the excel document. I would like the excel document to be opened with physically opening it.
Regardless, it does not work. What's really weird is that when I print msgbox lastRow, the value is wrong!